# How to speed up excel conversion in php with large data and multiple function calls

Tags: php, excel, csv

My sample php script looks like below. I want to save my database data into Excel format. Here i have table which has 35 columns. I need to display 16 to 18 thousands of data in this table. There are multiple functions to get data for different columns.

This script is working but it takes 8-10 minutes to get the excel file. The size of this output excel file is 18mb.

I think these multiple function calls for each row and the large file size is the reason of this slowness.

```
    include('../include/functions.php'); //includes functions
    $sql_query=$sql; //here $sql is some sql query
    $result_details=mysql_query($sql_query);

     $data=
    '<table border="1">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold">
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            .
            .
            .
            <td>Title n</td>

        </tr>';

    while(($row_details=mysql_fetch_array($result_details))){           
     $data.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.function_1($row_details['col-1']).'</td> //some function function_1 to get first column
            <td>'.function_2($row_details['col-2']).'</td> //some function function_2 to get second column
            .
            .
            .
            <td>'.function_n($row_details['col-n']).'</td>  //some function function_n to get nth column                                
        </tr>';
            }
    $data.='</table>';  

    $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
    $file_name= "details.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print $data;
```

I would appreciate any help where i can speed up my excel file conversion.
thank you.

Comment: You talk about generating csv, your code shows that you're actually generating html markup, and you're sending xls headers.... there's no consistency in this at all, and you don't appear to understand different file formats.... If you want to save as csv, then save as csv

Answer (score 3):

Generate a real csv file rather than confusing csv/html/xls

```
include('../include/functions.php'); //includes functions
$sql_query=$sql; //here $sql is some sql query
$result_details=mysql_query($sql_query);

$file_type = "text/csv";
$file_name= "details.csv";
header("Content-Type: $file_type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
... other headers here

$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
while($row_details = mysql_fetch_array($result_details)){
    fputcsv($fh, $row_details);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to speed up this work:

- add to your query this => `" ... INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`
- show this temporary file from disk with you headers

> ```
> header("Content-type: text/csv");
> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As you are taking lot of data into memory by appending it into $data variable. You need to change approach little bit.

First in loop write every row directly into file instead of appending to $data. That will keep ram usage less. After writing all rows, directly use `readfile` function to read file with excel headers.

That should speed up the excel build/download process.

```
$file_path= "/tmp/details.xls";
$file_name= "details.xls";
$fp = fopen($file_path, "a");

$data =
    '<table border="1">
        <tr style="font-weight:bold">
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            .
            .
            .
            <td>Title n</td>

        </tr>';
fwrite($fp, $data);
while(($row_details=mysql_fetch_array($result_details))) {
    $data =
        '<tr>
            <td>'.function_1($row_details['col-1']).'</td> //some function function_1 to get first column
            <td>'.function_2($row_details['col-2']).'</td> //some function function_2 to get second column
            .
            .
            .
            <td>'.function_n($row_details['col-n']).'</td>  //some function function_n to get nth column                                
        </tr>';
            } 
     fwrite($fp, $data);        
}
$data = '</table>';
fwrite($fp, $data); 
fclose($fp); 

$file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";

header("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($file_path);
```